# 3D object detection for custom objects; dataset creation

Tags: 3d, object-detection, tensorflow-datasets, point-cloud-library, point-clouds

How can I create a custom dataset for 3D object detection, I want to use the "Stanford3dDataset" or "Scannet" as baseline and add my object of interest in the dataset. I have the PCD files captured from the 3D camera [Realsense] and for 3D object detection, I am using the Pointnet model.

I see the dataset has the text file as input instead of PCD or PLY format, how do I convert PLY/PCD files to text files.

Comment: How did it go ? Can you guide me to train similar model on custom objects ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

import open3d as o3d

import numpy as np

## Load saved point cloud

pcd_load = o3d.io.read_point_cloud("try.ply")

## convert PointCloud to numpy array

xyz_load = np.asarray(pcd_load.points)

## Save points into a text file

np.savetxt('test.txt', xyz_load)`

More information is available in the link - [NumPy <-> open3d.PointCloud](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/tutorial/Basic/working_with_numpy.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can refer to this repository on github for reading a ply file https://github.com/HuguesTHOMAS/KPConv/blob/master/utils/ply.py  after reading the contents from the ply file you can simply use numpy.savetxt() to convert the ply file to text file

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I have used the open3d to solve it.